# Will other perks level up when not active?

Tags: killing-floor

I recently got medic up to level 5, which entitles me to spawn with body armour, making it my number one choice at the beginning of the game.

However, the medi-gun isn't exactly the strongest weapon, so to get around this I save up for a crossbow or eventually even a grenade launcher in the later levels.

Will kills with the crossbow and grenade launcher level up my Sharpshooter and Demolitions perks, respectively? How about if I use my pistol for head-shots (Sharpshooter), or buy a flame-thrower (Firebug), or a AK-47 (Commando), etc?

I'm wondering if I could still level up my other perks if my team needs a medic role.

Comment: If your team is at all competent you should be able to survive the clots on wave 1 without any armor.  In that case, how about starting out as a level 6 sharpshooter to get the free crossbow?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you can level up non-selected perks, provided you're using a proper weapon (or healing others).

On low difficulties I commonly pick up a Bullpup no matter what Perk I'm currently using, to avoid "wasting" stalker kills.

Answer (score 4):

A perk will gain experience whenever the specified action occurs. Whether or not the perk is active doesn't matter.

Comment: Didn't know who to accept since you both gave good answers, but he gave a little blurb about his own experience so I choose him, no hard feelings ;)

Comment: @hammythepig He needs the 15-rep more than I do :)

Comment: Ah, thanks. I upvoted your answer, since it was also accurate. We were 18 seconds apart, according to the timestamp when I posted. :)