# Do i have to select a perk in order to level it?

Tags: killing-floor

As you know, there are some [Perks](http://kf-wiki.com/wiki/Perks) in Killing Floor, and each of them, level by a different mechanism (Headshots, Melee Damage, Shotgun damage etc).

The question is, do i have to SELECT a perk in order to level it, or it will level even if not selected ?

E.g. With the Demolition Perk Selected, will my headshots count towards leveling Sharpshooter ?

With the Sharpshooter perk Selected, will my Heals count towards to level Medic Perk ?

Thanks!

Comment: This is the exact same as my question, already answered before: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/79850/will-other-perks-level-up-when-not-active

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you do not have to select a perk in order to level it, though it helps tremendously.